# Apache Nutch writing crawled docs to rabbitmq

Tags: java, hadoop, plugins, rabbitmq, nutch

Currently I have the elastic indexer plugin writing docs in batches to elastic. I now want to write these to a rabbitmq exchange.

I tried writing to the exchange inside the elastic plugin's write method and while this worked when run manually from local it did not work when run in the hadoop cluster.

I've also looked at publish-rabbitmq plugin but this looks event focussed rather than document.

Is there an available plugin to do what I want or do I need to write my own?

Answer (score 0):

You're after and indexing plugin similar to https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/master/src/plugin/indexer-solr but that works for RabbitMQ, at the moment this is not exist. I've done something similar for a client some time ago, but sadly is not open source.

Basically what you need to do is write your own implementation in a class that extends from `IndexWriter` and just fill the implementation for each method.

Take a look at the `indexer-solr`, `indexer-elastic` and https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/plugin/indexer-dummy/ which is the simplest and provided exactly as a learning/testing tool.

Comment: If I wish to have both indexing to elastic and to rabbit is it possible to run them side by side?

Comment: My recomendation would be to add a worker that consumes from the RabbitMQ queue and index then into ES. But otherwise you could accomplish that from the Nutch side as well, by enabling several indexing plugins.